# Updating the ServerURL in an existing MDM profile on iOS device

Tags: ios, mobile, profile, mdm

I am writing an iOS MDM server and wanted to update the ServerURL property in the MDM payload in an already enrolled iOS device.

Can I update it without removing the MDM profile first?

When I try to install the profile again over an existing one I get an error:
4001 - Profile Failed to Install
4015 - Remove the profile “XXX” before installing this profile.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the 4001 error because you are trying to change the server URLs.

The MDM server can replace the configuration profile which contains the MDM payload only if:

- The new profile also contains a MDM payload, and
- The URLs of the server in the new payload are the same as the old payload, and
- The topics are the same, and
- The new payload contains no new access rights